# Smooth function extension

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, differential-topology, differential

Can a smooth function $f : D\to\mathbb{R}^{n}$ where $D \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a closed perfect subset be extended to $g:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$ where $g$ is a smooth function and $g|_D = f$.
Smooth function mean $C^{\infty}$ functions.

Comment: Consider putting any mathematical expressions entirely in between `$` delimiters. For example, instead of `*f :D$\rightarrow$$R^{n}$*`, try `$f:D \rightarrow R^n$` or `$f: D \to \Bbb R^n$`.

Comment: [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/375530/81360) is related

Comment: Yes, even if $D$ is just closed, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/173806/is-it-possible-to-extend-an-arbitrary-smooth-function-on-a-closed-subset-of-rn).

Comment: What is the definition of a smooth function on a non-open subset?